# Alexandroff compactification: continuous function extension

Tags: general-topology, continuity, filters, compactification, topological-stacks

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a non compact topological space, $\infty \notin X$ and $(X^* := X \cup \{\infty\}, \mathcal{T}^* := \{U \subseteq X^*\mid U \cap X \in \mathcal{T} \land (\infty \in U \implies X \setminus U \mathrm{\ compact)}\})$ the Alexandroff compactification of $X$.

Let $(Y, \mathcal{S})$ be a Hausdorff space, and let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous function. Prove that the following statements are equivalent:

(1) $\operatorname{stack}\{f(X \setminus K) \mid K \subseteq X \mathrm{\ compact}\}$ converges

(2) There exists a unique continuous function $f^*: X^* \to Y$ with $f^*\vert_X = f$

**My attempt**:

$(1) \implies (2)$ Suppose $\operatorname{stack}\{f(X \setminus K) \mid K \subseteq X \mathrm{\ compact}\} \to y \in Y$

Define $f^*$ as the extention of $f$ such that $\infty \mapsto y$. This seems the only thing I can do now. I now have to show that this function is continuous, and I have no clue how I should do this. I also have to show this is unique, and I think I can use an argument that any image of $\infty$ other than $y$ will make the continuity of $f^*$ fail in that particular point.

$(2) \implies (1)$ Probably this follows from the fact that for any filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X^*$, $\mathcal{F} \to x \implies \operatorname{stack}f({\mathcal{F}})\to f^*(x)$, by continuity of $f^*$, but I cannot see what filter to use. If I would make an educated guess, I would say that $\{f(X \setminus K) \mid K \subseteq X \mathrm{\ compact}\}$ is a filter that converges to $\infty$.

Can anyone fill in the gaps?

Comment: Usually a space $X$ is called compact if (1) it is Hausdorff and (2) every open cover has a finite subcover. If we only require (2), the space is called quasi-compact. This is what you mean in your question. But, admittedly, notation is not completely standardized in the literature. Anyway, we should be aware that the space $X$ in your question is not required to be Hausdorff.

Comment: With compactness, I mean what you call quasi compact. There are no restrictions on $X$, just that it is not "quasi-compact"

Comment: What do you mean by $stack(\mathcal{M})$ when $\mathcal{M}$ is a suitable family of subspaces of $Y$? Is it the filter generated by $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: Exactly that yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By construction $X$ is a dense open subset of $X^\ast$.

$(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ $f^\ast$ is defined as in your attempt. Since $X$ is open in $X^\ast$, $f^\ast$ is continuous in all points of $X$. To show that it is also continuous in $\infty$, let $V$ be a neighborhood of $y$ in $X^\ast$. Since $\text{stack}\lbrace f(X \backslash K) \mid K \subset X \text{ compact} \rbrace \to y$, we know that $V \in \text{stack}\lbrace f(X \backslash K) \mid K \subset X \text{ compact} \rbrace$. Hence there exists a compact $K$ such that $f(X \backslash K) \subset V$. But $X^\ast \backslash K$ is an open neighborhood of $\infty$ since $X \backslash (X^\ast \backslash K) = K$ is compact, and clearly $f^\ast(X^\ast \backslash K) \subset V$. Uniqueness of $f^\ast$ is due to the well-known fact that the set of points where two continuous maps $u,v : Z \to Y$ agree is closed in $Z$ provided $Y$ is Hausdorff (recall that $X$ is dense in $X^\ast$).

$(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ $\mathcal{F} = \lbrace X^\ast \backslash K \mid K \subset X \text{ compact} \rbrace$ is a filter-base in $X^\ast$ which converges to $\infty$. By continuity of $f^\ast$, $f^\ast(\mathcal{F})$ converges to $y$. But $f^\ast(X^\ast \backslash K) = \lbrace y \rbrace \cup f(X \backslash K)$ so that $\text{stack}\lbrace f(X \backslash K) \mid K \subset X \text{ compact} \rbrace \to y$.

You see that you came very close to this.

Comment: I understand almost everything in your answer but why is $X^*\setminus K$ open? I.e., why is $X \cap (X^*\setminus K)$ open in $X$?

Comment: @Math_QED We have $\infty \in X^\ast \backslash K$ and $X \backslash (X^\ast \backslash K) = K$ which is compact.

Comment: Look at the topology. There are two conditions to be open.

Comment: @Math_QED Yes, my fault! This means that (1) has to be replaced by (1') $\text{stack}\lbrace f(X \backslash K) \mid K \subset X \text{ closed and compact} \rbrace$ converges. This tightened condition is automatically satisfied for Hausdorff $X$. With the original condition I don't see how to get a proof.

Comment: Many thanks! That's explains a bunch!