# Dominate any positive function from a topological space by a series of compactly supported functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

> If $X$ is a $\sigma$-compact, locally compact Hausdorff topological space and $\varphi \colon X \to [0, \infty]$ is some function, then is it always true that there exists a sequence of non-negative, continuous, compactly supported functions $(\varphi_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{C}_c(X,[0,\infty))$ such that $$\varphi \leq \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\varphi_k$$

I know that it would be enough, if we were able to find a sequence of ascending compact subsets $K_n$ of $X$ with $K_n \subset \text{int}(K_{n+1})$ and $\bigcup K_n =X$, but how would we go about constructing such a sequence under the given assumptions?

Comment: You should add your definition of $\sigma$-compact. Does it include locally compact?

Comment: @Paul Frost In my lecture notes it is defined without assuming the space to be locally compact, i.e. a space is defined to be $\sigma$-compact if there exists a sequence of compact subsets $K_n$ so that $X =\bigcup K_n$.

Comment: Does compact include Hausdorff?

Comment: @Paul Frost He didn't explicitly define compactness of sets, in that case I just assumed the definition to be the standard one. I think what we would need to make this work is, that $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, that admits to a sequence of ascending compact sets $K_n$ which satisfy $\bigcup K_n=X$ and $K_n \subset \text{int}(K_{n+1})$. We would then be able to apply a version of Urysohn that actually gives us the existence of compactly supported functions $\varphi_n$ which would do the job.

Comment: Maybe as a side note; we use this to define the $L^p$ spaces for functions with values in Banach spaces.

Comment: I suggest that you answer your own question. In fact it seems that you have to restrict to $\sigma$-compact and locally compact spaces which agree with those having an ascending sequence as in your comment. But I can't see that  separable is needed.

Comment: @Paul Frost I may overlook something completely trivial now, but how does local compactness, that is each $x \in X$ has a compact neighborhood, along with $\sigma$-compactness imply that we may find such a sequence of $K_n$ with $K_n \subset \text{int}(K_{n+1})$?

Comment: A comment is too short to answer that point. It is a new question with a new answer.

Comment: @Paul Frost Could you maybe make this into an answer and I will update my question accordingly? It would be very interesting

Comment: I can do so, but please make precise if you require $X$ to be Hausdorff. If not, things become unpleasant. It is not even clear what the adequate definition of local compactness is in that case: Existence of some compact neighborhood or of arbitrarily small compact neighborhoods?

Comment: @Paul Frost I have updated my post accordingly. It is totally fine if you assume $X$ to be Hausdorff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space $X$ is $\sigma$-compact if it can be written as the countable union of compact subsets. Therefore one can find a sequence of compact subsets $K_n$ of $X$ with $K_n \subset K_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup K_n =X$. However, we do not necessarily find a sequence of compact subsets $K_n$ of $X$ with $K_n \subset \text{int}(K_{n+1})$ and $\bigcup K_n =X$. Call such a sequence *strongly ascending*. Clearly, the existence of a strongly ascending sequence of compact subsets implies $\sigma$-compactness.

Note that there is a subtle point concerning the notion of compactness. Some authors understand this to include *Hausdorff*, other authors do not. In my answer I shall not assume it.

Let us now define a space $X$ to be *locally compact* if each $x \in X$ has an open neighborhood whose closure is compact and to be *strongly locally compact* if for each $x \in X$ and each open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\overline V$ is compact and $\overline V \subset U$. In my opinion the latter is the better concept, but there is no real standard. Anyway, if $X$ is Hausdorff, then both concepts agree. An example where they differ is the Alexandroff compactification $\alpha(\mathbb Q)$ of the rationals $\mathbb Q$. This space is compact, hence locally compact, but not strongly locally compact. See my answer to [An example of a compact topological space which is not the continuous image of a compact Hausdorff space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2793040).

Let us prove

Lemma. $X$ admits a strongly ascending sequence of compact subsets if and only if $X$ is $\sigma$-compact and locally compact.

Proof. (1) Let $X$ admit a strongly ascending sequence of compact subsets $K_n$. Then $X = \bigcup \text{int}K_{n+1}$, hence each $x \in X$ is contained in some $\text{int}K_{n+1}$ so that $K_{n+1}$ is a compact neigborborhood of $x$. Therefore $X$ is locally compact.

(2) Let $X$ is $\sigma$-compact and locally compact. Write $X= \bigcup C_n$ with $C_n$ compact. By induction we construct a sequence of compact $K_n \subset X$ such that
$$(*) \quad K_i \cup C_i \subset \text{int}(K_{i+1})$$
for all $i$. Then $(K_n)$ is strongly ascending.

For $n=1$ let $K_1 = C_1$. Assume we have found $K_1,\ldots, K_n$ such that $(*)$ is satisfied for all $i < n$. We now construct $K_{n+1}$. By local compactness each $x \in K_n \cup C_n$ has an open neighborhood $U(x)$ such that $D(x)  =\overline{U(x)}$ is compact. Since $K_n \cup C_n$ is compact, there are finitely many $x_i \in K_n \cup C_n$ such that $K_n \cup C_n \subset V = \bigcup_{i=1}^r U(x_i)$. Let $K_{n+1} = \bigcup_{i=1}^r D(x_i)$. This is a compact set such that $K_n \cup C_n \subset V \subset K_{n+1}$. But since $V$ is open, we get $K_n \cup C_n \subset \text{int}(K_{n+1})$.

For your purposes you need a strongly ascending sequence of compact subsets. To apply Urysohn's Lemma, you must assume that the $K_n$ are closed and normal. This is automatically satisfied if $X$ is Hausdorff. If it is not, then you get fairly technical assumptions concerning a very special strongly ascending sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great answer. Very enlightening! :)