# Bijective, continuous, proper function between locally compact Hausdorff topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm currently reading Topology by Munkres. I found this question online from an assignment some dude did for his topology class like back in 2017 or something like that and I'm in the process of working on it.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are locally compact, Hausdorff topological spaces and let $f:X \to Y$ be one-to-one, onto, continuous and proper (pre-images of compact sets are compact). Prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

My question: Given that the function is continuous and bijective, it should be enough to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

The sets are locally compact, so for each $x \in X$ and each $y \in Y$, there is some compact subspace of $X$ and $Y$ that contains a neighbourhood of $x$ and $y$ respectively. But if the function is proper, that is to say, the pre-images of compact sets are compact and compact sets are closed by definition, wouldn't the pre-images of these closed sets also be closed? Is this not enough to conclude that $f^{-1}$ is continuous?

Thanks in advance for any tips or advice.

Comment: It is a little complicated to talk about the inverse of the inverse... pre-images of closed sets are closed because $f$ is continuous. You want to show that the image of closed sets is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @HennoBrandsma's answer, I'd like to suggest one with a characterization of Hausdorff locally compact by means of the intersection of compact neighbourhoods.

For a given point $x$ in a topological space, let $\mathcal{F}(x)$ denote the closed neighbourhoods of $x$. Notice (exercise) that being Hausdorff can be translated to
$$\bigcap \mathcal{F}(x) = \{x\}$$
for every $x$. That is, the intersection of every closed neighbourhood of $x$ is just $\{x\}$.

Now, let $\mathcal{K}(x)$ denote the compact neighbourhoods of $x$. If the Hausdorff space is also locally compact, then, $\mathcal{K}(x) \neq \emptyset$, and so,
$$\{x\} \subset \bigcap \mathcal{K}(x) \subset \bigcap \mathcal{F}(x) = \{x\}.$$

Now, in order to show that, given a closed $C \subset X$, $f(C)$ is closed, take $b \in \overline{f(C)}$, and $a \in X$ such that $b = f(a)$. Now, the family
$$f^{-1}(K) \cap C,\quad \text{for $K \in \mathcal{K}(b)$}$$
is made from compact closed sets and has the finite intersection property. Therefore,
$$\bigcap_{K \in \mathcal{K}(b)} \left(f^{-1}(K) \cap C\right) \neq \emptyset$$
But,
$$\bigcap_{K \in \mathcal{K}(b)} f^{-1}(K) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{K \in \mathcal{K}(b)} K\right) = f^{-1}(\{b\}) = \{a\}.$$
Therefore, $a \in C$. And so, $b \in f(C)$. Since $b$ was arbitrary in $\overline{f(C)}$, $f(C)$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

I love to use the [one-point compactification](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/one-point+compactification) in this case! :-)

If $X$ (and $Y$) is compact, the proposition is very easy to prove, because being closed and being compact in a compact Hausdorff space is just the same thing. And since the image of compact sets by a continuous function is compact, you have that the function takes closed sets to closed sets and its inverse is therefore continuous.

A locally compact Hausdorff space can be embedded in its [one-point compactification](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/one-point+compactification): $\tilde{X} = X \cup \{\infty_X\}$ and $\tilde{Y} = Y \cup \{\infty_Y\}$. The open neighbouhoods of $\infty_Y$, for instance, are of the form $\tilde{A} = \{\infty_Y\} \cup A$, where $Y \setminus A$ is compact.

Saying that a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is proper, is just the same as saying it can be continuously extended to
$$\tilde{f}: \tilde{X} \rightarrow \tilde{Y}$$
by setting $f(\infty_X) = \infty_Y$. To check it is continuous at $\infty_X$, just verify that
$$\tilde{f}^{-1}\left(\tilde{A}\right)^c = f^{-1}\left(\tilde{A}^c\right)$$
is compact and therefore, it is a neighbouhood of $\infty_X$.

So, $\tilde{f}$ is a homeomorphism. Since $X$ and $Y$ are embedded (they have the topology induced by $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$, $f$ is also a homeomorphism.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2787461.

Comment: Can you explain this notation? While one-point compactification is defined in Munkres, I haven't seen this notation before. $\tilde{X} = X \cup \{\infty_X\}$

Comment: @WannaBeRealAnalysist: I had to add one new point to $X$ and one new point to $Y$. So, I called them $\infty_X$ and $\infty_Y$. Maybe I should have simply used $\infty$ for both... or $p$ and $q$...

Answer (score 1):

I like proofs with nets (optional topic in Munkres, do it first; a generalised sequence which "works" in all topological spaces; a convenient tool to have.)

It is also enough to show that $f$ is closed. So let $C \subseteq X$ be closed, and we want to see that $f[C]$ is also closed in $Y$. So let $y \in \overline{f[C]}$ and let $K_y$ be compact neighbourhood of $y$. Also let $x$ be the unique point so that $f(x)=y$. By continuity and properness $f^{-1}[K_y]$ is a compact neighbourhood of $x$. There is some net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ in $C$ so that $f(x_i) \to y$ by $y$ being in the closure of $f[C]$. WLOG we can assume that $(x_i)$ lies in $f^{-1}[K_y]$ (switch to a tail set) and by compactness we have a convergent subnet $(x_{c(j)})$ (with connecting map $c: J \to I$, say) converging to some $x' \in f^{-1}[K_y]$. But as $f(x_{c(j)}) \to f(x) = y$ by being a subnet and by continuity of $f$ we have $f(x_{c(j)}) \to f(x')$ we have $f(x')=y$ by Hausdorffness of $Y$ and so $x'=x$ by injectivity. And as all $x_{c(j)}$ lie in $C$ which is closed, it follows that $x \in C$ and $y \in f[C]$. Hence $f[C]$ is closed, and thus $f$ is a closed map and we're done.

Comment: So I use that continuity implies "net convergence continuity", compact is equivalent to "all nets have convergent subnets" and Hausdorff implies "net limits are unique". Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) for info.

Comment: I don't use Hausdorffness or local compactness in $X$ at all (but after we show the homeomorphism, it turns out to be necessary anyway, right?)

Comment: I think there is some theorem about a proper continuous map to a $k$-space being always closed, so that's fastest if you know about that and the fact that loc. cpt. Hausdorff spaces are $k$-spaces (aka compactly generated spaces).